# Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.map is not a function

Tags: javascript

here is my code:

```
function employee(rex1){
    const rex = {...rex1}.map((key , value)=>{
        return `${key} : ${value}`


    })
    return `your result is ${rex.join(',')}`
}
console.log(employee({name : 'ahmed' , age : 20})
```

and it get error as below:

> Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)}.map is not a function

Comment: Objects do not have a `map` method. Arrays do ~ [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. To make a good answer here, please be sure to include more detail about your question, state exactly what you need help with, and properly format your code. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to iterate over the key / value pairs in an object, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to retrieve them as an array in the form

```js
[[key1, val1], [key2, val2], ... [keyn, valn]]
```

For example

```js
function employee(rex1) {
  const rex = Object.entries(rex1).map(([key , value]) => `${key} : ${value}`)

  return `your result is ${rex.join(',')}`
}
console.info(employee({name : 'ahmed' , age : 20}))
```